# Prestashop Product-prices.tpl file IF statement for tax problem

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem as i am not able to correct this statment on PS 1.7 product-prices.tpl file
basically i want to check if the tax is "$ 0" for the product shall show abc, and if not "$ 0" then show xyz. but i guess the `$product.tax_rate` is not getting the correct value of the product tax.

```
`{if $product.tax_rate eq "$ 0"}  
<span> abc </span>
{else}
<span> xyz</span>
{/if}`
```

Comment: Have you tried to do a `var_dump` of `$product.tax_rate`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer how to get achive this

```
`{assign var="tax_amount" value=Context::getContext()->currentLocale- >formatPrice($product.price_tax_exc, $currency.iso_code)}
            {if {$tax_amount} == {$product.price}} 
            abc 
            {else}
            xyz
            {/if}`
```